# Connection refused Android Api

Tags: java, android, api, http, httpurlconnection

Good afternoon. I am trying to connect Android app to http://localhost:3000/ ( but in code I use an emulator's ip). 
The error is "W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused"
Could you help me to find an error? Other posts were not useful for me.

```
    public String execute() {
        String line;
        StringBuilder outputStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder(baseUrl + urlResource);
            if (!urlPath.equals("")) {
                urlString.append("/" + urlPath); }
            if (parameters.size() > 0 && httpMethod.equals("POST")) {
                payload = getPayloadAsString();
                urlString.append("?" + payload);  }
            URL url = new URL(urlString.toString());
            String encoding = Base64Encoder.encode(email + ":" + password);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod(httpMethod);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
            connection.connect();
            if (httpMethod.equals("GET") || httpMethod.equals("PUT")) {
               payload = getPayloadAsString();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                try {
                    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
                    writer.write(payload);
                    headerFields = connection.getHeaderFields();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        outputStringBuilder.append(line);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {}
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            else {
                InputStream content = (InputStream) connection.getInputStream();
                headerFields = connection.getHeaderFields();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    outputStringBuilder.append(line);}    }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); }
        if (!outputStringBuilder.toString().equals("")) {
            lastResponse = outputStringBuilder.toString(); }
        return outputStringBuilder.toString(); }}
```

Comment: Provide the error log

Comment: @ShaishavJogani W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:334)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)